# PHP: Converting JSON object with varying keys to CSV

Tags: php, json, csv

I am trying to convert a JSON object with overlapping keys to CSV.

The JSON structure looks like this:

```
[
 {"key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"},
 {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"},
 {"key3": "value3"}
]
```

The order of the keys is always the same, but which keys are present in each entry can vary. The goal is a CSV like this:

```
key1   , key2   , key3
0      , value2 , value3
value1 , value2 , value3
0      , 0      , value3
```

I have tried rewriting [this example](https://gist.github.com/Kostanos/5641110) using [array_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php), but without luck as i am lacking experience with PHP. The example uses the keys in the first entry as headers. The problem is, that the first entry in my data is not guaranteed to contain all possible keys.

I feel like there exists a fairly simple solution to this problem, i just can't crack it.

Any advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: just loop over the entire set to get all the keys, then loop over again to set the values

Comment: Iterate the decoded JSON array, check if key exists; if yes use the value, if not insert a zero into the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$json = '[{"key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},{"key3":"value3"}]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

// Gets a list of all the 2nd-level keys in the array
function getAllUniqueKeys($array)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $sub) {
        $result = array_merge($result, array_keys($sub));
    }
    return array_unique($result);
}

$uniqueKeys = getAllUniqueKeys($array);
//$uniqueKeys = [
//   "key2",
//   "key3",
//   "key1",
// ];

$csv = [];
$csv[] = $uniqueKeys; //putting unique keys as header

foreach ($array as $sub) {
    $row = [];
    foreach ($uniqueKeys as $uniqueKey) {
        if (array_key_exists($uniqueKey, $sub)) {
            $row[] = $sub[$uniqueKey];
        } else {
            $row[] = 0;
        }
    }
    $csv[] = $row;
}
```

now `$csv` is equal to:

```
[
    ["key2", "key3", "key1",],
    ["value2", "value3", 0,],
    ["value2", "value3", "value1",],
    [0, "value3", 0]
];
```

if you want to sort unique keys you can use it as `sort($uniqueKeys);` after this `$uniqueKeys = getAllUniqueKeys($array);`

Answer (score -1):

This code doesn't work if dinamic keys

```js
let csv = 'key1 , key2 , key3 \n';

let json = [
 {"key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"},
 {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"},
 {"key3": "value3"}
];

for (let data of json) {
  let key1 = data['key1'];
  let key2 = data['key2'];
  let key3 = data['key3'];
  key1 = key1 !== undefined ? key1 : '  ';
  key2 = key2 !== undefined ? key2 : '  ';
  key3 = key3 !== undefined ? key3 : '  ';
  
  csv += `${key1} , ${key2} , ${key3}\n`;
}
console.log(csv);
```